# Sending Message to Arduino From Raspberry Pi with NRF240l1

Tags: pi-2, arduino

I'm trying to send string from Raspberry Pi from Arduino. I can pong out and pong back. But can't send string. I changed main code. I can't send. Here is my Raspberry Code..

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <RF24/RF24.h>

using namespace std;
RF24 radio(22,0);
bool radioNumber = 1;
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  bool role_ping_out = true, role_pong_back = false;
  bool role = role_pong_back;

  cout << "RF24/examples/GettingStarted/\n";
  radio.begin();

  radio.setRetries(15,15);
  radio.printDetails();
  printf("\n ************ Role Setup ***********\n");
  string input = "";
  char myChar = {0};
  cout << "Choose a role: Enter 0 for pong_back, 1 for ping_out (CTRL+C to exit) \n>";
  getline(cin,input);

  if(input.length() == 1) {
    myChar = input[0];
    if(myChar == '0'){
        cout << "Role: Pong Back, awaiting transmission " << endl << endl;
    }else{  cout << "Role: Ping Out, starting transmission " << endl << endl;
        role = role_ping_out;
    }
  }

    if ( !radioNumber )    {
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
    } else {
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
    }

    radio.startListening();

    while (1)
    {
        if (role == role_ping_out)
        {
            radio.stopListening();

            printf("Now sending...\n");
            unsigned long time = millis();

            unsigned char message[16] = "Hello, Arduino!";
            bool ok = radio.write( &message, sizeof(unsigned char) * 16);


            if (!ok){
                printf("failed.\n");
            }
            radio.startListening();

            unsigned long started_waiting_at = millis();
            bool timeout = false;
            while ( ! radio.available() && ! timeout ) {
                if (millis() - started_waiting_at > 200 )
                    timeout = true;
            }
            if ( timeout )
            {
                printf("Failed, response timed out.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                unsigned long got_time;
                radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

                printf("Got response %lu, round-trip delay: %lu\n",got_time,millis()-got_time);
            }
            sleep(1);
        }

        if ( role == role_pong_back )
        {

            if ( radio.available() )
            {
                unsigned long got_time;

                while(radio.available()){
                    radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );
                }
                radio.stopListening();

                radio.write( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

                radio.startListening();

                printf("Got payload(%d) %lu...\n",sizeof(unsigned long), got_time);

                delay(925); 
            }

        }

    }

  return 0;
}
```

The code is just example of maniacbug's library. I changed something for sending string. I mean just changed pipes, and make this

```
bool ok = radio.write( &time, sizeof(unsigned long));
```

to this

```
unsigned char message[16] = "Hello, Arduino!";
bool ok = radio.write( &message, sizeof(unsigned char) * 16);
```

In my arduino side just pong back opinion changed. 
    #include 
    #include "nRF24L01.h"
    #include "RF24.h"
    #include "printf.h"

```
//
// Hardware configuration
//

// Set up nRF24L01 radio on SPI bus plus pins 9 & 10 

RF24 radio(9,10);

//
// Topology
//

// Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

//
// Role management
//
// Set up role.  This sketch uses the same software for all the nodes
// in this system.  Doing so greatly simplifies testing.  
//

// The various roles supported by this sketch
typedef enum { role_ping_out = 1, role_pong_back } role_e;

// The debug-friendly names of those roles
const char* role_friendly_name[] = { "invalid", "Ping out", "Pong back"};

// The role of the current running sketch
role_e role = role_pong_back;

void setup(void)
{
  //
  // Print preamble
  //

  Serial.begin(57600);
  printf_begin();
  printf("\n\rRF24/examples/GettingStarted/\n\r");
  printf("ROLE: %s\n\r",role_friendly_name[role]);
  printf("*** PRESS 'T' to begin transmitting to the other node\n\r");

  //
  // Setup and configure rf radio
  //

  radio.begin();

  // optionally, increase the delay between retries & # of retries
  radio.setRetries(15,15);

  // optionally, reduce the payload size.  seems to
  // improve reliability
  //radio.setPayloadSize(8);

  //
  // Open pipes to other nodes for communication
  //

  // This simple sketch opens two pipes for these two nodes to communicate
  // back and forth.
  // Open 'our' pipe for writing
  // Open the 'other' pipe for reading, in position #1 (we can have up to 5 pipes open for reading)

  //if ( role == role_ping_out )
  {
    //radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
    radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
  }
  //else
  {
    //radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
    //radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
  }

  //
  // Start listening
  //

  radio.startListening();

  //
  // Dump the configuration of the rf unit for debugging
  //

  radio.printDetails();
}

void loop(void)
{
  //
  // Ping out role.  Repeatedly send the current time
  //

  if (role == role_ping_out)
  {
    // First, stop listening so we can talk.
    radio.stopListening();

    // Take the time, and send it.  This will block until complete
    unsigned long time = millis();
    printf("Now sending %lu...",time);
    bool ok = radio.write( &time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

    if (ok)
      printf("ok...");
    else
      printf("failed.\n\r");

    // Now, continue listening
    radio.startListening();

    // Wait here until we get a response, or timeout (250ms)
    unsigned long started_waiting_at = millis();
    bool timeout = false;
    while ( ! radio.available() && ! timeout )
      if (millis() - started_waiting_at > 200 )
        timeout = true;

    // Describe the results
    if ( timeout )
    {
      printf("Failed, response timed out.\n\r");
    }
    else
    {
      // Grab the response, compare, and send to debugging spew
      unsigned long got_time;
      radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

      // Spew it
      printf("Got response %lu, round-trip delay: %lu\n\r",got_time,millis()-got_time);
    }

    // Try again 1s later
    delay(1000);
  }

  //
  // Pong back role.  Receive each packet, dump it out, and send it back
  //

  if ( role == role_pong_back )
  {
   if( radio.available()){
      while (radio.available()) {  
        char message[16];
        radio.read( &message, sizeof(char) * 16); 
        Serial.print(F("Got message: "));
        Serial.println(String(message));
      }

      radio.stopListening(); 
      radio.startListening();   
   }
  }

  //
  // Change roles
  //

  if ( Serial.available() )
  {
    char c = toupper(Serial.read());
    if ( c == 'T' && role == role_pong_back )
    {
      printf("*** CHANGING TO TRANSMIT ROLE -- PRESS 'R' TO SWITCH BACK\n\r");

      // Become the primary transmitter (ping out)
      role = role_ping_out;
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
    }
    else if ( c == 'R' && role == role_ping_out )
    {
      printf("*** CHANGING TO RECEIVE ROLE -- PRESS 'T' TO SWITCH BACK\n\r");

      // Become the primary receiver (pong back)
      role = role_pong_back;
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
    }
  }
}
// vim:cin:ai:sts=2 sw=2 ft=cpp
```

I really dont know. How can i send it? Where is my failure?